# How do I use a global state in WAI middleware?

Tags: haskell, scotty

I am writing a web server using Scotty. The server should have a login route that once user logs in, a token is dispatched and recorded in the server. Obviously the recorded tokens should be in a global state (not using Redis kind of thing because the server is run on single machine and has small view counts).

Now I know the Scotty examples have shown how to define and access global states in routes, but I can't find out how to do the same thing for middlewares.

I tried using the same way from [the official example](https://github.com/scotty-web/scotty/blob/master/examples/globalstate.hs) but neither the middleware function nor the app function has a WebM monad context so I can't really do this:

```
app = do
  tokensList <- webM $ gets tokens
  middleware $ authMiddleware tokensList
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That "official example" isn't so great.  I mean, it's a good example of using a custom monad, but it's a lousy example of how to provide global state.  You don't need the custom monad at all.  You just need the `TVar`.

Ultimately, all you need to do is create the `newTVar` in `main`, and then pass it to the `app` function to construct the application and middleware, which can access the `TVar` directly with lifted `IO` operations in the application and `IO` operations in the middleware.  It'll look something like the following:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  state <- newTVar startState
  scotty 3000 $ app state

app :: TVar AppState -> ScottyM ()
app state = do
  middleware (authMiddleware state)
  get "..." $ do
    x <- liftIO $ readTVarIO state
    ...

authMiddleware :: TVar State -> MiddleWare
authMiddleware state app req resp = do
  x <- readTVarIO state
  ...
  app req resp
```

To illustrate, here's a rewrite of that official example without the monad that operates on the `TVar` directly in the handler.  (No middleware yet, but see the example further below.)

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main (main) where

import Web.Scotty
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.String

newtype AppState = AppState { tickCount :: Int }

main :: IO ()
main = do
  state <- newTVarIO (AppState 0)
  scotty 3000 $ app state

app :: TVar AppState -> ScottyM ()
app state = do
  get "/" $ do
    c <- liftIO $ tickCount <$> readTVarIO state
    text $ fromString $ show c
  get "/plusone" $ do
    liftIO . atomically $ modifyTVar' state (\(AppState n) -> AppState (n+1))
    redirect "/"
  get "/plustwo" $ do
    liftIO . atomically $ modifyTVar' state (\(AppState n) -> AppState (n+2))
    redirect "/"
```

and here's a version that uses middleware to count page accesses and queries and resets the value from the handlers, all directly through the `TVar` without requiring any custom monad:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main (main) where

import Web.Scotty
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.String
import Network.Wai

newtype AppState = AppState { tickCount :: Int }

main = do
  state <- newTVarIO (AppState 0)
  scotty 3000 $ app state

app :: TVar AppState -> ScottyM ()
app state = do
  middleware $ countMiddleware state
  get "/" $ do
    c <- liftIO $ tickCount <$> readTVarIO state
    text $ fromString $ show c
  get "/reset" $ do
    liftIO . atomically $ writeTVar state (AppState 0)
    redirect "/"

countMiddleware :: TVar AppState -> Middleware
countMiddleware state appl req resp = do
  liftIO . atomically $ modifyTVar' state (\(AppState n) -> AppState (n+1))
  appl req resp
```

Comment: Thanks. So I indeed have been wondering why this extra monad context WebM is needed and this explains quite clear that it isn't.